# Use encoded object query param for GET request

Tags: httprequest, urlencode, url-encoding, query-string

While designing the API with with the team a suggestion was forwarded in regards to some complex query parameters that we sent which need to be encoded as objects, arrays of objects, etc. Suppose I have a route `GET /resource/` and I want to apply a set of filters directly in the query params. The object literal structure of this filter would be something like

```
filter: {
  field1: {
    contains: 'value',
    notin: ['value2', 'value3']
  },
  field2: {
    greaterThan: 10
  }
}
```

Encoding this in the url, via a query string parser such as the `qs` node module that express.js uses internally, would be cheap on the backend. However 1) The generated url is very hard to read, if a client wants to connect with the API he would need to use an encoding library and 2) I don't think I ever encountered the use of query params like this, it looks a little bit of overengineered and I'm not sure how used it is and if it is really safe.

The example above would yield query params such as:

```
GET /resource/?field1%5Bcontains%5D=value&field1%5Bnotin%5D%5B0%5D=value2&field1%5Bnotin%5D%5B1%5D=value3&field2%5BgreaterThan%5D=10
```

Does this practice of sending url query parameters that happen to be complex objects have some standards or best practices?

Answer (score 1):

We implemented a different solution for filtering, when the list of possible parameters was very long. We ended up doing it in two steps, posting the filter and returning a filter ID. The filter ID could then be used in the GET query.

We had trouble finding any best practices for this.